# VirtualBox becomes slow after running in the background for a while on MacOS X Catalina

Tags: macos, virtualbox

## Background

I run a Mac OS X Catalina, Apache, PHP 7.3, SQL Server 2012 stack on my mac. 
Obviously SQL Server will not run on a mac so it is run on a Virtual Box Windows 10 Professional machine with network routing on port 1433.

## The Problem

My local host website moves very fast most of the time. However if the Virtual Box has not been accessed for a certain amount of time (as in physically opening the vm window and manipulating something in the OS the site slows from ~1sec loads to as high as 30sec loads. I select the VM and it immediately speeds up again to normal speed. This issue is exaggerated when I run on battery power and in about 30sec after I leave the VM window the performance drop occurs.

## The Question: What is happening and how do I stop it?

I suspect Mac OS is throttling background processes to protect battery life and free up resources. It could be doing this to hard drive access or processor access to achieve the same effect. Is this a fair evaluation? Is their a setting in Virtual Box or Mac OS or service I can use to prevent this specific process from being back-burnered?

Answer (score 0):

So turns out the issue was completely unrelated to virtual box. I was using a custom domain name for the local copy of the website. "mysite.local" Mac has reserved the ".local" domain extension for internal use. So while it works it has very inconsistent performance sometimes responding to the dns request in moments other times taking up to 30sec. The issue is indeed more pronounced while on battery and more pronounced when I have virtual box running I assume whatever dns service is running is being throttled or overworked.

**The solution: Change the ".local" domain to just about anything else.**

I changed it to ".dson" and have not had the issue since. I read this solution in another stack exchange question but I have been unable to re-locate it